# How to resolve problem of .bak database backups disappearing from inside the folder

Tags: python, sql

Good night people. I'm developing software that backs up a database using SQL SERVER. Basically, a problem that I've been having with all the versions I release is that on some clients that this system runs, on random days, the backup happens to disappear from within the folder that the software itself creates. For example, the software starts the database backup process, the .bak file appears created inside the folder and right after the backup is finished, the .bak file disappears inside the folder.

As this system already runs on some servers, I was able to observe that this problem has already happened on operating systems such as windows server 2012, windows 10, etc.

Here's the snippet of code where he tries to perform the backup.

```
def backup_diario(backup):  

    try:
        conexao = sqlserver.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='+servidor+';DATABASE='+backup+';UID='+usuario+';PWD='+ senha)
        cursor = conexao.cursor()

    except Exception as erro:
        send_to_txt(erro)
        pass

    else:
        day = time.strftime('%d')
        month = time.strftime('%m')
        year = time.strftime('%Y')
        folder = f'{year}{month}{day} alwaysdb' 
        try:
            os.chdir(f'{diario}') 
        except Exception as erro:
            send_to_txt(erro)
            pass
        else:
            try:
                os.mkdir(folder)
            except:
                pass

            try:
                conexao.autocommit = True
                cursor.execute(F"BACKUP DATABASE {backup} TO DISK = '{diario}{folder}\\{backup}.bak' WITH INIT")  
  
            except Exception as erro:
                send_to_txt(erro)
                pass
```

Basically I tried to restructure all the backup code, putting more exceptions to see if it showed something different. The problem is that for the software, apparently everything is fine, as it does not display any type of error. I tried using time.sleep to see if it changes something too

Comment: there's one exception you're not catching, and not raising either, which can easily create hard to find bugs. Try printing that error also, the one with os.mkdir(folder)

I also don't know what this send_to_txt does, but instead of pass, I would write raise, and look at your server logs. Then you get full stack traces.

Comment: Hello man. Thanks for your comment! 
I looked at the logs directly through the windows server log viewer and several messages appeared with this type of error: Log Name: Application
Source: MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS
Date: 01/21/2023 03:18:56
Event ID:3041
Task Category:Backup
Description:
BACKUP does not complete the BACKUP DATABASE CAP command. Check the backup application log for logged messages.

Comment: I will be trying to use your other tips to solve the problem. thank you again

Comment: Did you found out what the issue was, I  have exactly the same problem?